# htaccess redirect on pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess

how can I have a pattern with regular expression using htaccess what would redirect all incoming links

from `example.com/test-en/` to `example.com/test/`

it should be filtered out if after root domain name the string contains the suffix -en, if match redirect.

here is the hole code what I'm trying to do

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://www.example.co.uk [NC]
**RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)-en/$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]**
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do that:

```
RewriteRule /?test-[a-zA-Z]{2}/ /test/
```

Comment: @user1659575 can you add a second example?

Comment: I mean test-en can be something else it depends on request

Comment: Are there some structures? Like that there are some chars at the beginning then comes a minus sign and a two letter language identifier...

Comment: that suffix is added if the tag is a translated version

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-en/?$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: do you have something else in your htaccess ??

Comment: quite lot of stuffs it begins like RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301] and I was putting your code after this

Answer (score 0):

You have the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)-en/$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But you asked for a redirect without a `/tag` in front. (and for a different domain), but if you want the tag preserved, you need to add that in your target:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)-en/$ http://www.example.co.uk/tag/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Otherwise, that rule works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: thanks for your feedback I'm gonna give try with it and I will give you a feedback soon